# Best practice/way to get value where id = something on a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
[{'id': 360004373520, 'value': something1}, {'id': 360004411159, 'value': something2}, {'id': 360004373540, 'value': something}]
```

I would like to get the value where id = xxxxxxxxxxxx.

Which would be the fastest way?

Comment: By "I would like to get the value where id = xxxxxxxxxxxx.", do you mean that for example "you would like to get the value where id = ``360004411159``" expecting the output "``something2``"? Can there be more than one dict/value with the same id? Will there always be at least one dict/value with the desired id?

Comment: ```[j for j in l.values() if j==xxxx]```

Comment: yes, @MisterMiyagi. The first thing that you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `next()` built-in method:

```py
lst = [
    {"id": 360004373520, "value": "something1"},
    {"id": 360004411159, "value": "something2"},
    {"id": 360004373540, "value": "something"},
]

to_search = 360004411159

value = next(d["value"] for d in lst if d["id"] == to_search)
print(value)
```

Prints:

```
something2
```

---

Or: If you search multiple times, it's worth considering transforming the list to dictionary:

```py
to_search = 360004411159


dct = {d["id"]: d["value"] for d in lst}
print(dct[to_search])
```

Comment: with the first option, will break when it founds the variable to search, right? in order to don't iterate all the dictioanries

Comment: @ToninoFernandez Yes, that's true, it will break when the match has been found.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible solution:

```
for key in lst:
    if key['id']=='xxxxxx':
       #do something
```